# Laravel Provider Cannot Accessing Data in provider in all my views

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a provider in a module called ReportsServiceProvider. I trying to access data from all views but im not getting the items i want. The query below works well in a controller but fails in the provider.
My code looks like this:

```
public function boot()
     {
        {
            view()->share('invoices', function () {
                $builder = DB::table('invoice_items')
                    ->select(
                        [
                            DB::raw("DISTINCT invoice_items.uuid"),
                            'invoices.number AS invoice_number',
                            'invoices.date_closed',
                            'invoice_items.name AS service_name',
                            'invoice_items.total_amount',
                            'invoice_items.amount_paid',
                            'invoice_items.balance',
                            'visits.created_at',
                            'payment_mode_visits.payment_mode',
                            'visits.id AS visit_id',
                            'visits.ended_at',
                            'clinics.name',
                            'patients.first_name',
                            'patients.last_name',
                            
                        ]
                    )
                    ->join('invoices', 'invoices.id', 'invoice_items.invoice_id' )
                    ->join('visits', 'visits.id', 'invoices.visit_id')
                    ->join('patients', 'patients.id', 'visits.patient_id')
                    ->join('clinics', 'clinics.id', 'visits.clinic_id' ) 
                    ->leftJoin('payment_mode_visits', 'payment_mode_visits.visit_id', 'invoices.visit_id')
                    ->where('invoice_items.amount_paid', '>', 0);
        
                    return $builder->get();
                });
        }

    }
```

When i dump `$invoices` in any view i get this

```
Closure() {#1016 ▼
  class: "Modules\SouthLakeAnalytics\Providers\ReportsServiceProvider"
  this: Modules\SouthLakeAnalytics\Providers\ReportsServiceProvider {#193 …}
  file: "/var/www/html/medyq-web-core/modules/SouthLakeAnalytics/Providers/ReportsServiceProvider.php"
  line: "42 to 72"
}
```

What im i doing wrong?

Comment: you are sharing a closure and in the view are getting that closure, i dont understand what you expect to happen otherwise

Comment: @lagbox I thought ,my items would display. Or am i not supposed to access them with ```$invoices```

Comment: you are getting what you are sharing, a closure, it does not execute it for you, you would have to do that